# Mysterious file appeared on Windows 10 and can't be deleted. Where does it come from?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am using Win10 on Lenovo Ideapad 320 and I recently noticed that strange file on my background with the name `¨.`. Yes, the name of the file is `¨.`.

I think it appeared sometimes while I was plugging in extra screen to my laptop. Interesting thing that if I try to delete it I get the notice: Could not find this item. I have tried to use CMD, same resolution.

I want to delete this file, but more than that would like to know where toes it come from and why.

[image: ScreenshotWeirdFile]

[image: CmdNotification]

Comment: Are you truly interested in where it came from (vs. how to delete it)? If so, know that it's unlikely anyone here can answer that question.

Comment: When you ran "del" did you copy-paste the full name of the file in?  Or did you just type it?  The file could have non-US-English language or keyboard characters in it name.

Comment: Did the file's recent appearance coincide with the installation of any software or other activity?  As TwistyImpersonator mentioned, it will be almost impossible for anyone here to guess at the file's origin.

Comment: Please take a look at the circled keys on this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/ritKn.png . Is the filename the same as two apostrophes (green key) followed by a comma, a quotation mark (green key plus shift) followed by a comma, or the accent grave https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent followed by a comma ?

Comment: It seems like two dots but located on the position as apostrophes followed by comma, try to see ScreenshotWeirdFile I have uploaded. If it would be impossible to find out where does file come from, I would be equally happy to delete it. I have tried to use the full path  but no success, same message can't find the file

Comment: Try deleting from within a Live Linux boot and see if it succeeds.

Comment: In CMD, does the filename show up on the list if you run the DIR command on your desktop directory?  I think I found the first character ¨ in the Lucida Console font in Character Map, it appears to be character "Diaeresis" [Alt+0168].  No idea where the file came from but, if it appears in the file list using the DIR command, you may be able to delete it using the asterisk wildcard after the diaeresis [e.g.  del ¨* ].

Comment: It shows up on a list with DIR yes.And yes, I deleted it with wildcard, "del ¨*" did the job

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I submitted my suggestion as an answer.  If you're satisfied with it, please accept it as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the first character ¨ in the Lucida Console font in Character Map, it appears to be character "Diaeresis" [Alt+0168]. No idea where the file came from, but if it appears in the file list using the DIR command, you can delete it using the asterisk wildcard after the diaeresis [e.g. del ¨* ].

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the above answers:

Maybe you need to track the file ?

For this you might use the Event Viewer Log.

E.g.

> Event ID :
> 4656
> A handle to an object was requested
> Logs the start of every file activity but does not guarantee that it succeeded
>
> 4663
> An attempt was made to access an object
> Logs the specific microoperations performed as part of the activity
>
> 4660
> An object was deleted
> The only way to verify an activity is actually a delete
>
> 4658
> An object was closed
> The handle to an object was closed      How much time it took

useful Script : [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-audit-changed-39afba72)

source : [here](https://blog.varonis.com/windows-file-activity-monitoring-event-log/)

To add a custom event:

> click 'Create Custom View'
>
> Select 'By Log'
>
> pull down 'Event Logs'
>
> Checkmark 'Windows Logs'
>
> Move to the field  and copy and paste in the event id numbers
>
> click OK and name the view.